# Understanding the logic behind a piece of C code

Tags: c

I would love if you guys could explain to me why the following piece of recursive code doesn't print the word 'test'. Thanks in advance.

```
void drawTetriminosEachPosition(int **tetriminos, char **dBoard, int **tBoard, int i){
  char c;
  char **dBoard2;

  if(tetriminos[i] == '\0')
  {
      return;
  }    
  else
  {
     dBoard2 = dBoard;
     DrawTetrimino(tBoard, tetriminos[i], dBoard, i+65);
  }
  i++;
  return (drawTetriminosEachPosition(tetriminos,dBoard,tBoard,i));

  ft_putstr("test");
  if(checkChar(tBoard,tetriminos[i]))
  {
      dBoard = dBoard2;
      return (drawTetriminosEachPosition(tetriminos,dBoard,tBoard,i));
  }     
}
```

Comment: why should it print `"test"`? anything after the `return` statement doesn't get executed

Comment: seems i still don't understand recursive well enough , i thought that once the tetriminos[i] == '\0' it would return to the previous call of the drawTetriminosEachPosition and continue from that point

Comment: But you're returning! Remove the return - just call the function before the ft_putstr.

Comment: it does, except that there is another `return` statement right there (`return (drawTetriminosEachPosition(tetriminos,dBoard,tBoard,i));`) which means the next "step" in the execution is to `return` out of the function *again*

Comment: yeah i'll go ahead and remove both returns and rethink the logic , thanks guys this was really helpful i was stuck on it for 1 hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements after a return are never executed. Since the first

```
return (drawTetriminosEachPosition(tetriminos,dBoard,tBoard,i));
```

does not depend on any condition, the following code is not executed.

Comment: Thanks i think i know how to fix it now

Answer (score 1):

When control reaches `return ...` it simply returns and next lines are not executed. Maybe you missed some logic in between?

As of now you can delete this part  it doesn't matter

```
ft_putstr("test");
  if(checkChar(tBoard,tetriminos[i]))
  {
      dBoard = dBoard2;
      return (drawTetriminosEachPosition(tetriminos,dBoard,tBoard,i));
  }
```

Comment: ok now i understand where i got it wrong thanks , gonna give this to koala since he was first